# loop through array using split() to separate items by commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, split

I have trouble splitting the values of `Months` and putting each values into a select box using `.each`. I used the following code and `split()` didn't have any effect at all. I got a select box with two options but the values weren't separated into each option.

JSON data:
`[{"Title":"DataTitle","Months":"January,February","Location":"Africa"}]`

Code:

```
var item_html ='';
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.jsonfile.com/json",
    success: function (data) {
     item_html = pData(feedformat,data);
     $('.displayarea').append(item_html).slideDown();
    },
  error: function ()        
});

function pData(type, data) { 
     switch(type) {
       case 'Case1':
          item_html += '<h3>'+item.Title+'</h3>;'

          if(item.Months.length !== 0) {
               var Months = item.Months.split(",");
               item_html += '<select>';
               $.each(Months,function(i){
                 item_html += '<option>'+Months+'</option>';
               });
               item_html += '</select>';
          }

          item_html += '<h3>'+item.Location+'</h3>';
```

The result I got with the code above was:

```
<select><option>January,February</option><option>January,February</option></select>
```

What I'm looking for is

```
<select><option>January</option><option>February</option></select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Erm, the result rendered 2 options, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @BGerrissen, sorry, I made a mistake. That's what I'm looking for. But the result I'm getting is `<select><option>January,February</option><option>January,February</option></select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(Months,function(i){
    item_html += '<option>'+Months[i]+'</option>';
});
```

instead of

```
$.each(Months,function(i){
    item_html += '<option>'+Months+'</option>';
});
```

**Another thing is your JSON `item` is an array object.**

```
item =[{"Title":"DataTitle","Months":"January,February","Location":"Africa"}];

item_html ="";
item_html += '<h3>'+item[0].Title+'</h3>';
if(item[0].Months.length !== 0) {
    var Months = item[0].Months.split(",");
    item_html += '<select>';
    $.each(Months,function(i){
       item_html += '<option>'+ Months[i] +'</option>';
    });
    //or
    //$.each(Months,function(i, month){
    //   item_html += '<option>'+ month +'</option>';
    //});
    item_html += '</select>';
 }
 item_html += '<h3>'+item[0].Location+'</h3>';

$('.displayarea').append(item_html).slideDown();
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WS57/7/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
        $.each(Months,function(i){
             item_html += '<option>'+Months+'</option>';
        });
```

to:

```
        $.each(Months,function(i, month){
             item_html += '<option>'+month+'</option>';
        });
```

You're putting all the months in each option, not just the current month from the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
 var Months = item.Months.split(",");
 item_html += '<select>';
 $.each(Months,function(i){
   item_html += '<option>'+ Months[i] +'</option>';
 });
 item_html += '</select>';
```

`Months` this is an array object. So you need to get current array item from the iteration.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5WS57/4/)

Answer (score 1):

the solution...

```
function pData(type, data) { 
     switch(type) {
       case 'Case1':
          item_html += '<h3>'+item.Title+'</h3>;'

          if(item.Months.length !== 0) {
               var Months = item.Months.split(",");
               item_html += '<select>';
               $.each(Months,function(i){
                 item_html += '<option>'+Months.split(",")[i]+'</option>';
               });
               item_html += '</select>';
          }

          item_html += '<h3>'+item.Location+'</h3>';
```